# What is best practice for connection database with asp.net webapplication?

Tags: asp.net

Asp.net provides `sqldatasource` control for working on databases and we can also do same thing using code ,so which one should I use?

Comment: The _less you know_ the more advisable it is for you to opt for tooling to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

[SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the other classes of the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace allow you to connect to SQL Server through code. This is the easiest choice if you are familiar working with SQL statements directly.

Another common way to access SQL databases through .NET code is to use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool such as *Entity Framework* or *NHibernate*.